# I'm looking for the title of a book that dates back to the 70s about a disease that turns people to stone

Tags: story-identification, books

I  read a book as a teen, and I can't remember the name. 
It was about a disease of some kind that turned people into stone. Regular doctors couldn't find a cure, but there was a secret path (hidden in road signs) that led to a group of people who'd figured out a way to make victims into fully functioning, indestructible people. As best I can recall, it was called something like "The Hidden Highway"
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [***Highways in Hiding***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highways_in_Hiding) by George O. Smith.

> *The novel concerns ESP and a disease that turns men into supermen. It
>   contains multiple plotlines concerning the interactions of people that
>   can sense things (espers) and people that can read thoughts
>   (telepaths). This is set against the plot of a secret society that is
>   harboring people that are infected with a spaceborne illness called
>   Mekstrom's Disease. **The disease is the point on which the plot turns.
>   People get infected and it slowly turns them into a sort of rock. The
>   hardening begins at one of the extremities such as a finger or toe and
>   slowly begins to creep up the infected limb.** Eventually all the
>   extremities are hardening and the disease makes its way to the body
>   proper. At this point, the body is hardened until the vitals fail and
>   the patient dies. **The plot turns on a secret society that has found a
>   cure for the infected. To hide themselves from the public at large
>   they have devised a hidden highway program that leads the infected to
>   "Mekstrom safehouses" of sorts.***

[image]