# Read a yellowed paperback in 1983. Involved pinprick finger itch eventually turning body to stone

Tags: story-identification

Set in rural America maybe midwest. Cryptic, hidden road signs lead to safe houses where mutated humans learn to survive without causing attention to their super strength caused by body having turned to stone.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: duplicate of this question:https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180136/im-looking-for-the-title-of-a-book-that-dates-back-to-the-70s-about-a-disease-t/180139#180139